# File Upload in Java OFBiz?

Tags: java, ofbiz

I have a form that has an option for uploading file

```
<form type="upload" name="myForm" target="rgUsrStory">
      <field name="st_title" title="${uiLabelMap.uStoryTitle}"><text/></field>
      <field name="upload_file" title="${uiLabelMap.UploadFile}"><file/></field>
      <field name="submitButton" title="${uiLabelMap.submit}"><submit/></field>
</form>
```

request map:

```
<request-map uri="rgUsrStory">
     <security https="true" auth="true"/>
      <event type="java" path="org.ofbiz.webapp.control.usrStory" invoke="rgUsrStory" />
    <response name="success" type="view" value="main"/>
    <response name="error" type="view" value="login"/>
</request-map>
```

The event function is working properly, but i need to upload the file also to the server and details of that file to the table named as 'documents', but i don't know how to do that, i searched throw the web but only i found using `ftl`, also want to control the file type of defined file that i want to display those file types as allowed file in form during adding user story.
For any guide and help thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look at the image upload functionality in the OFBiz content manager.

There's a form

```
<form name="ImageUpload" target="uploadImage" title="" type="upload"  default-map-name="currentValue"
    header-row-style="header-row" default-table-style="basic-table">
    <field name="dataResourceId" title="${uiLabelMap.ContentDataResourceId}"><display/></field>
    <field name="dataResourceTypeId" ><hidden/></field>
    <field name="objectInfo" title="${uiLabelMap.ContentUploadedFile}"><display /></field>
    <field name="imageData" entity-name="ImageDataResource" title="${uiLabelMap.ContentFile}"><file/></field>
    <field name="submitButton" title="${uiLabelMap.CommonUpload}" widget-style="smallSubmit"><submit button-type="button"/></field>
</form>
```

The corresponding request in the controller.xml

```
<request-map uri="uploadImage">
    <security auth="true" https="true"/>
    <event invoke="persistContentAndAssoc" path="" type="service"/>
    <response name="success" type="request" value="UploadImage"/>
    <response name="error" type="view" value="UploadImage"/>
</request-map>
```

The service name in services.xml lead you to the service method

```
<service name="persistContentAndAssoc" engine="java" transaction-timeout="7200"
        location="org.ofbiz.content.ContentManagementServices" invoke="persistContentAndAssoc" auth="true">
    <description>Create a Content, DataResource and/or ContentAssoc</description>
    <permission-service service-name="genericContentPermission" main-action="CREATE"/>
    ...
</service>
```

In `org.ofbiz.content.ContentManagementServices#persistContentAndAssoc` the uploaded file is read by

```
ByteBuffer imageDataBytes = (ByteBuffer) context.get("imageData");
```

(the corresponding form field).

You will find some other functionality like dealing with the mime type there.

Comment: Thanks for guide, is it possible to do this without service just using Java event?

Comment: Yes, just change your request configuration from type 'service' to 'event' and specify the full qualified classname in 'path'.

Comment: Brohi tanks for help. But i have one another problem when i use java event and import `import java.io.FileOutPutStream` and other related `io` package,  many error like `can not find symbol import java.io.FileOutPustStream` and for `import org.apache.commons.fileupload.fileItem` error occur that says `package org.appache.commons.fileupload  does not exist`. so how i can solve that thanks again.

Comment: @jones Please provide your code so that we can take further analysis. There are some typos in the above import statements so that **could** be the problem.
Please accept my answer above if it fits the original answer, thank you!